# Read large file error "outofmemoryerror"(java)

Tags: java, arrays, string, out-of-memory

sorry for my english. I want to read a large file, but when I read error occurs **outOfMemoryError**. I do not understand how to work with memory in the application. The following code does not work:

```
try {

    StringBuilder fileData = new StringBuilder(1000);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    char[] buf = new char[8192];
    int bytesread = 0, 
        bytesBuffered = 0;

    while( (bytesread = reader.read( buf )) > -1 ) {

        String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, bytesread);
        bytesBuffered += bytesread;

        fileData.append(readData); //this is error

        if (bytesBuffered > 1024 * 1024) { 
            bytesBuffered = 0;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(fileData.toString().toCharArray());
} finally {

}
```

Comment: What's the highest possible Java version you can use? Reading files in that way is pretty outdated, except you need to use Java 6 because of Android or something. Otherwise you should use the Stream API of Java 8.

Comment: I use 1.70_71 . I need to read large files, not readLine(). because file (5GB) can contain only one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need pre allocate a large buffer to avoid reallocate.

```
File file = ...;
StringBuilder fileData = new StringBuilder(file.size());
```

And running with large heap size:

```
java -Xmx2G
```

==== update

A while loop using buffer doesn't need too memory to run. Treat input like a stream, match your search string with the stream. It's a really simple state machine. If you need search multiple words, you can find a TrieTree implementation(support stream) for that.

```
// the match state model
...xxxxxxabxxxxxaxxxxxabcdexxxx...
         ab     a     abcd

    File file = new File("path_to_your_file");
    String yourSearchWord = "abcd";
    int matchIndex = 0;
    boolean matchPrefix = false;
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        int chr;
        while ((chr = reader.read()) != -1) {
            if (matchPrefix == false) {
                char searchChar = yourSearchWord.charAt(0);
                if (chr == searchChar) {
                    matchPrefix = true;
                    matchIndex = 0;
                }
            } else {
                char searchChar = yourSearchWord.charAt(++matchIndex);
                if (chr == searchChar) {
                    if (matchIndex == yourSearchWord.length() - 1) {
                        // match!!
                        System.out.println("match: " + matchIndex);
                        matchPrefix = false;
                        matchIndex = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    matchPrefix = false;
                    matchIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And that's okay if for example the 10GB file use this `StringBuilder fileData = new StringBuilder(file.size());`?

Comment: Can you describe the the operations you will do with 10GB file? The process may be vary depends on your job.

Comment: I need a large file (5-10gb) to find a string that contains the desired word. I do not know how to do it, maybe too much character-oriented or multi-part download. It would be great to find what that example.

Comment: Reading a file line by line does not fit. For example if we have only one line and the file contains 5GB, then the application will fall. I checked the code on file in 500MB, and the application fell on the line `while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)`, error **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:**

Comment: Try the new edited examples. If you stream it's not a character file, just wrap them like `GZIPInputStream`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This might be helpful :-

```
try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String txt = "";
    while( (txt = reader.read()) != null){
        System.out.println(txt);
    }
}catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println("Error : "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. This error in  `txt = reader) != null`, Unresolved compilation problem: Type mismatch: cannot convert from BufferedReader to String.

Comment: @qazqwerty sorry my bad...its `reader.read()`. See the modified code

Comment: @qazqwerty also dont forget to accept(tick) an answer if it helps you

Comment: And if you have a file like 5 GB and there is only one line, the application does not fall? `reader.readLine()` I do not seem to fit

Answer (score 0):

You should not hold such big files in memory, because you run out of it, as you see. Since you use Java 7, you need to read the file manually as stream and check the content on the fly. Otherwise you could use the stream API of Java 8. This is just an example. It works, but keep in mind, that the position of the found word could vary due to encoding issues, so this is no production code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileReader
{
    private static String wordToFind = "SEARCHED_WORD";
    private static File file = new File("YOUR_FILE");
    private static int currentMatchingPosition;
    private static int foundAtPosition = -1;
    private static int charsRead;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file))
        {
            System.out.println("Total size to read (in bytes) : " + fis.available());

            int c;
            while ((c = fis.read()) != -1)
            {
                charsRead++;
                checkContent(c);
            }

            if (foundAtPosition > -1)
            {
                System.out.println("Found word at position: " + (foundAtPosition - wordToFind.length()));
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Didnt't find the word!");
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void checkContent(int c)
    {
        if (currentMatchingPosition >= wordToFind.length())
        {
            //already found....
            return;
        }

        if (wordToFind.charAt(currentMatchingPosition) == (char)c)
        {
            foundAtPosition = charsRead;
            currentMatchingPosition++;
        }
        else
        {
            currentMatchingPosition = 0;
            foundAtPosition = -1;
        }
    }
}
```